# calculated field in MS ACCESS database

Tags: ms-access-2007, ms-access-2003

I am new to access database. I have a Payroll Table with several fields. In that table whenever I insert a new row in to that table, I want to display netpay field to be filled automatically. I want to calculate

```
 [Grosspay] - [OtherExpenses].
```

Im  Googled and saw many examples but I am not getting the exact one  what I wanted. In one example I found changing the datatype of automated calculated field to Calculated datatype. But in my database I don't find that.  I am using access 2007

Comment: The calculated field datatype was introduced in Access 2010.  It is not supported in earlier Access versions.  For Access 2007, you can use your calculation as a query field expression.

Comment: @HansUp I have created a query for calculating net pay and I am getting the output as well, but mu question is How can I apply these query for a field(to be calculated automatically).